# ggplot2: Add points to geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a line-plot in ggplot2 and I want to add points (=shapes) for each data row to clearly identify it. I do not(!) need a shape/point at every data-point but instead some values would be sufficient. See the following example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
d=data.table(x=seq(0, 100, by=0.1), y=seq(0,1000)))
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_line()
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

[image: Line Only]
[image: With added points]

Due to the huge number of samples, the shapes are not visible anymore but overdraw each other. I only need some of them, perhaps a equidistant spacing would look the best, but I'm open to any other solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also add some points, just thin the data with an index.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
d=data.table(x=seq(0, 100, by=0.1), y=seq(0,1000))
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_line()
#Change the length parameter for fewer or more points
thinned <- floor(seq(from=1,to=dim(d)[1],length=70))
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_line()+geom_point(data=d[thinned,],aes(x=x,y=y))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can plot points at certain quantiles with `quantile`. For example, the following sequence generates deciles.

```
quantile(rnorm(100), probs = seq(0, 1, .1))
#         0%         10%         20%         30%         40%         50%         60%         70%         80%         90%        100% 
#-2.43934306 -1.17208001 -0.91497203 -0.69489868 -0.46306926 -0.24133438 -0.03434118  0.39989589  0.72331902  1.06402664  2.02892420 

library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(x = seq(0, 100, by=0.1), y = seq(0,1000))

ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y))+
geom_line()+
geom_point(aes(x = quantile(x, probs = seq(0, 1, .1)),
               y = quantile(y, probs = seq(0, 1, .1))))
```

[image: Plot with points at deciles]

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to add a `data.table` solution that can work with grouped data as well:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

# Creates data from the Weibull distribution
weib_dt <- function(x = seq(0, 4.0, 0.01), w_shape = 1, w_scale = 1) {
  y = dweibull(x, shape = w_shape, scale = w_scale)
  data.table("shape" = as.factor(w_shape), "scale" = as.factor(w_scale), "x" = x, "y" = y)
}

dt_a <- weib_dt(w_shape = 0.5)
dt_b <- weib_dt(w_shape = 1.0)
dt_c <- weib_dt(w_shape = 2.0)
# Bind multiple Weibull samples together, created from different parametrizations
dt_merged <- rbindlist(list(dt_a, dt_b, dt_c))

# Create the plot, using all the points for the lines, and only 9 points per group for the points.
ggplot(dt_merged, aes(x, y, group=shape, color=shape)) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1.5)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data=dt_merged[, .SD[floor(seq(1, .N, length=9))], by=shape], 
             aes(x, y, group = shape,  color = shape, shape = shape))
```

The trick here is the use of `seq` as with the suggested solutions above, but this time it's done within the group (using `.SD`). Note that currently `.SD` can have bad performance, you can use the more verbose `dt[dt[, ..., by =shape]$V1]` if this is slow.

This will create the following output:

[image: Weibull plots]